# Table not found with hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto create

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-security, spring-data

I'm experimenting with Spring MVC and Spring Security, and encountered the following issue: I'm using H2 and have set hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto to create, but when I try to add a user record I get `org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "USER" not found`.

This is my database configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DatabaseConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource datasource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        datasource.setDriverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
        datasource.setUsername("sa");
        datasource.setPassword("");
        datasource.setUrl("jdbc:h2:mem:web");
        return datasource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(){
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean
                = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("mypackage.model");
        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factoryBean.setJpaProperties(this.additionalProperties());
        return factoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf){
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        return transactionManager;
    }

    private Properties additionalProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", "false");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
        return properties;
    }

}
```

This is the model:

```
@Entity
public class User implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    @ElementCollection
    private List<Role> authorities = new ArrayList<Role>();
    private Boolean accountNonExpired;
    private Boolean accountNonLocked;
    private Boolean credentialsNonExpired;
    private Boolean enabled;

    public User() {
        this.accountNonExpired = true;
        this.accountNonLocked = true;
        this.credentialsNonExpired = true;
        this.enabled = true;
    }

    // ...

}
```

This is the security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .antMatcher("/api/**")
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .httpBasic();
    }

}
```

And this is how I try to add a user for testing purposes:

```
@Autowired
private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

@RequestMapping("/init")
@ResponseBody
public String init() {

    User user = new User();
    user.setId(0L);
    user.setUsername("user");
    user.setPassword("password");
    customUserDetailsService.save(user);

    return "{name:'init'}";
}
```

Apparently the tables are created:

```
Hibernate: drop table User if exists
Hibernate: drop table User_authorities if exists
Hibernate: create table User (id bigint not null, accountNonExpired boolean, accountNonLocked boolean, credentialsNonExpired boolean, enabled boolean, password varchar(255), username varchar(255), primary key (id))
Hibernate: create table User_authorities (User_id bigint not null, authorities binary(255))
Hibernate: alter table User_authorities add constraint FK_6yei1bmvdwkqgfn4hw53bvqus foreign key (User_id) references User
[2014-12-04 03:20:32,045] Artifact web:war exploded: Artifact is deployed successfully
```

But when calling the `init()` method I get this:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "USER" not found; SQL statement:
select user0_.id as id1_0_0_, user0_.accountNonExpired as accountN2_0_0_, user0_.accountNonLocked as accountN3_0_0_, user0_.credentialsNonExpired as credenti4_0_0_, user0_.enabled as enabled5_0_0_, user0_.password as password6_0_0_, user0_.username as username7_0_0_ from User user0_ where user0_.id=? [42102-181]
    org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up your Url to.

```
datasource.setUrl("jdbc:h2:mem:web;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS<yourschema>");
```

See http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html for more info.

Comment: This didn't help right away, but I haven't studied the documentation yet. For now I have switched to HSQL, but I'll post back when I have looked into H2 again.