# Object not found when executing query with table in a schema

Tags: hibernate, hsqldb

I'm trying to set up a simple Spring context with hsqldb by using ddl auto create.  This is just for unit testing, as in production we are using postgresql.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
   ">
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:unittest;sql.syntax_pgs=true" />
    <property name="username" value="sa" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactoryBean" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.foo.service.analytics.google" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.archive.autodetection">class,hbm</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactoryBean" />
</bean>

<bean class="com.foo.service.analytics.google.GaDimensionDaoImpl" />
<bean class="com.foo.service.analytics.google.GaHibernateAdapterImpl" />

<context:annotation-config />
</beans>
```

The database creation succeeds per the logs:

```
Hibernate: drop table analytics.dim_date if exists
Hibernate: drop sequence seq_dim_location_sequence
Hibernate: create table analytics.dim_date (dim_date_id integer not null, date timestamp, hour integer, minute integer, primary key (dim_date_id))
Hibernate: create sequence seq_dim_location_sequence
```

Here is my entity:

```
package com.foo.service.analytics.google.dimensions;

import com.foo.service.analytics.google.DimensionAttribute;
import com.foo.service.analytics.google.GaDimensionDao;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Calendar;

@Entity
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(
            name = GaDimensionDao.GET_BY_DIM_ATTRIBUTES,
            query = "SELECT dim FROM DateDimension dim " +
                    "WHERE dim.date = :date " +
                    "AND (:hour IS NULL OR dim.hour = :hour) " +
                    "AND (:minute IS NULL OR dim.minute = :minute)"
    )
})
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seq_dim_location", sequenceName = "seq_dim_location_sequence",
    schema = "analytics", allocationSize = 1)
@Table(name = "dim_date", schema = "analytics")
public class DateDimension {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "dim_date_id", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq_dim_location")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "date")
    private Calendar date;

    @Column(name = "hour")
    private Integer hour;

    @Column(name = "minute")
    private Integer minute;
}
```

After using the NamedQuery, I get the following stacktrace:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: user lacks privilege or object not found: DIM_DATE in statement [select datedimens0_.dim_date_id as dim1_0_, datedimens0_.date as date0_, datedimens0_.hour as hour0_, datedimens0_.minute as minute0_ from analytics.dim_date datedimens0_ where datedimens0_.date=? and (? is null or datedimens0_.hour=?) and (? is null or datedimens0_.minute=?) limit ?]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1367)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1295)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:317)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:360)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30.getSingleResult(Unknown Source)
    at com.foo.service.analytics.google.GaDimensionDaoImpl.createOrGet(GaDimensionDaoImpl.java:50)
    at com.foo.service.analytics.google.GaHibernateAdapterImpl.processRow(GaHibernateAdapterImpl.java:79)
    at com.foo.service.analytics.google.GaHibernateAdapterImpl.convert(GaHibernateAdapterImpl.java:40)
    at com.foo.service.analytics.google.GaHibernateAdapterTest.createHibernateObjectFromGaTest(GaHibernateAdapterTest.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:81)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:216)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:82)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:67)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:162)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: user lacks privilege or object not found: DIM_DATE in statement [select datedimens0_.dim_date_id as dim1_0_, datedimens0_.date as date0_, datedimens0_.hour as hour0_, datedimens0_.minute as minute0_ from analytics.dim_date datedimens0_ where datedimens0_.date=? and (? is null or datedimens0_.hour=?) and (? is null or datedimens0_.minute=?) limit ?]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.ConnectionProxyHandler.continueInvocation(ConnectionProxyHandler.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy31.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:166)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1711)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:828)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:289)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2438)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2424)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2254)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2249)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:470)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:355)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1248)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:284)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: DIM_DATE in statement [select datedimens0_.dim_date_id as dim1_0_, datedimens0_.date as date0_, datedimens0_.hour as hour0_, datedimens0_.minute as minute0_ from analytics.dim_date datedimens0_ where datedimens0_.date=? and (? is null or datedimens0_.hour=?) and (? is null or datedimens0_.minute=?) limit ?]
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.prepareStatement(DelegatingConnection.java:281)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.prepareStatement(PoolingDataSource.java:313)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.ConnectionProxyHandler.continueInvocation(ConnectionProxyHandler.java:138)
    ... 55 more
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: DIM_DATE
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.readTableName(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.readTableOrSubquery(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadTableReference(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadFromClause(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadTableExpression(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQuerySpecification(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadSimpleTable(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryPrimary(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryTerm(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryExpressionBody(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryExpression(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.compileCursorSpecification(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compilePart(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.compileStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementManager.compile(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
    ... 64 more
```

Removing the `schema` value from the `@Table` annotation allows this to succeed.  I see the schema creation in the generated ddl statements as well as in the query in the stacktrace.  Is there something else that needs to be done to enable schemas with hsqldb without changing the bindings themselves?

For reference, I'm using Spring 4.1.1.Release, hsqldb 2.3.4, and Hibernate 4.1.3.Final.

**UPDATE**
I did get my goals satisfied by switching to H2 from HSQLDB, by manually creating the schema in an INIT param as stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27307568/550282).  Keeping this question open in case someone has an answer for HSQLDB as I could not find a solution anywhere.

Comment: Are you using a custom database user (did you create a user in the database) ? Because the stack trace is mentioning `user lacks privilege`

Comment: The only user involved should be the `sa` user used to create the datasource in the spring conf.  I'm using the same datasource for hibernate to generate the ddl as well as for the entitymanager.  I can play around with running a `GRANT` script... but I think it's simply not finding the schema.

Comment: Try to move the SequenceGenerator annotation from the class declaration to id field declaration, and remove the GeneratedValue annotation.

Comment: No luck with that either @TahaBasri.

Comment: There is a bug in Hibernate version 4. Try upgrading your Hibernate version. [bug link](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7232)

Comment: The bug you mention @TahaBasri is a good one to be aware of.  That said, the NamedQuery is just a `SELECT`, so it's not really an issue here, and an upgrade to Hibernate 5.x is a bigger move than I'm willing to make at the moment.  Just to confirm, I commented out the `@SequenceGenerator` and switched `@GeneratedValue` back to `AUTO` and the same error persists.